# Global Keyboard button press events

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have some issues trying to get a key press event to trigger by importing and using components from an external library.I'm using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) as a help in tracking global prntscreen key press events.

So i have added the reference to my vb.net project as seen [here](http://www.meepdevs.org/SaveImage.aspx?id=Ma4aSBKb) also i imported the library on my from.And it shows up on toolbar as a component. However i have trouble figuring out to getting the keypress event to work

```
Imports Gma.UserActivityMonitor
Partial Public Class Main

Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    AddHandler HookManager.KeyDown, AddressOf HookManager_KeyDown


    Me.NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub

 Private Sub HookManager_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.PrintScreen Then
        Dim img As Image = SnippingTool.Snip()
        PictureBox1.Image = img
    End If
End Sub
End class
```

these is the code i added to detect prntsceen button press but however it dosent get triggered , what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The print-screen key is special, a global hook doesn't capture it.  You can make it work by pinvoking RegisterHotKey() instead.  A sample form that shows the required code:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub PrintScreen()
        AppActivate(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
        MessageBox.Show("Print screen key pressed...")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
        If Not RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, HOTKEYID, 0, VK_SNAPSHOT) Then Throw New Win32Exception
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(e As FormClosingEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
        If Not e.Cancel Then UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, HOTKEYID)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
            Dim id = m.WParam.ToInt32()
            If id = HOTKEYID Then PrintScreen()
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub


    ''--- Pinvoke:
    Private Const HOTKEYID As Integer = 0
    Private Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312
    Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT As Integer = &H2C

    <DllImport("User32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function RegisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer, ByVal modifiers As Integer, ByVal vk As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function
    <DllImport("User32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function UnregisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Hey it seems to work with application minimized but when i put the application into system tray it says 

{"Process '{0}' was not found."}

Any idea how to get it to work with application in system tray

Comment: nvm i just got rid of the appactivate() thing and seems to work now. I hope its not something to do with any critical thing .. i really dont understand what the code here is doing but i can live with that lol it does what i want :D